# How to avoid a solution of zeros in a quadratic program?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, constraints

I want to find optimal $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^r$ that solves the following quadratic program:
$$
\min_{\beta \in \mathbb{R}^r}\;\; \left(G\beta\right)^{\prime}W\left(G\beta\right)\;\;\; \text{s.t.}\;\; ||\beta||_1 \leq c_1,
$$
where $G$ is a $q \times r$ matrix, and $W$ is a $q\times q$ positive definite and symmetric matrix.

As you can see, I am adding a "Lasso" constraint to a quadratic problem that has, as one of its solutions, the vector $\beta =\left(0,0,\cdots,0\right)$. I want to avoid this trivial solution. This is not the only solution.

I thought about adding a second constrait of the form $||\beta||_1 \geq c_2$. The problem with this approach is that the constraint is not convex.

My question is if there is a more convenient approach (that preserves convexity) to incorporate some restriction in the previous problem such that the trivial solution is not feasible.

Comment: For $r>q$, any solution to $G\beta=\mathbf{0}$ i.e. $G$'s nullspace yields the minimum. For $r\le q$, it can have nontrivial solution only if $G$ is not full rank. So even if you remove the trivial solution, there can potentially be many solutions, even with the LASSO constraint. The question is which one, and why is it more desirable than the trivial one?